# In Azure Synpase, how can I check how a table is distributed

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse, how can I check how a table is distributed. For example whether it is distributed in a round robin manner or with hash keys.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic, but your question isn't about PARTITION, it's about DISTRIBUTION. Definitely not the same thing and could be confusing to future folks who find this question. @wBob has a good answer for determining distribution type.

Comment: Had the same comment, updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Dynamic Management View (DMV) `sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties` in a dedicated SQL pool to determine if a table is distributed via round robin, hash or replicated, eg

```
SELECT 
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( object_id ) schemaName, 
       OBJECT_NAME( object_id ) tableName,
       *
FROM sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties;
```

It's the `distribution_policy_desc` column.  Some sample results:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse [distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/massively-parallel-processing-mpp-architecture#distributions) and [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition). I've updated the question.

---

`pdw_table_distribution_properties` is certainly a possibility as mentioned.

Or just generate the create DDL for that table using any Client (Data Studio, SSMS, VS Code with plugin, ...).

E.g. in Azure Data Studio, right click on the table and click "Script as Create".

[image]

Look for `DISTRIBUTION` in `WITH` clause.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sa_logs]
(
    [version_number] [float] NULL,
    [request_start_time] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    ...
    [referrer_header] [varchar](256) NULL,
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    HEAP
)
GO
```

or for a table with `HASH`:

```
...
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [hash_column] ),
...
```

---